# Sockets, understanding S_un in IN_ADDR

Tags: c++, sockets

I’m trying to understand S_un in [IN_ADDR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738571%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This is the output when my IP is 127.0.0.1:

[image: Output]

Information about the types:

```
S_un_b
An IPv4 address formatted as four u_chars.
S_un_w
An IPv4 address formatted as two u_shorts.
S_addr
An IPv4 address formatted as a u_long.
```

I can’t understand how S_un_w and S_addr are build. S_un_b is logic, each octet from my IP address is converted to a unsigned char. But how are the 2 unsinged shorts and the unsigned long build? Or did they just memcopyed 127001 in these variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just a union, so it shows the same data in three different representations.  Another way to look at it is to view the 4 byte integer (S_addr) as a hex value (and remember that 0x7f = 127):

```
16777343 = 0x100007F  ==> 01 | 00 | 00 | 7f
```

It is in little Endian format.

Comment: and the words as 0x0100 and 007f etc

Comment: Thanks, but why would someone do this? Wasn't it easier to output it as a byte[]?

Comment: I don't know if it would be simpler.  I suppose that would depend on the usage.  The structure as defined provides simple access to each individual byte.  In the sockets programming I have done (some ... not a lot) it would not have simplified anything, but maybe I just did not encounter a need for a byte array of the address.

Comment: That is also true. Thank you very much.